# Rearranging the order of divs in an RSS using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rss

I need to rearrange the div order of an RSS. Each item has 3 divs. I will need to move the div with the class "itemDate" before the div with the class "itemTitle" (see markup below). Should I use the function .each(); is there a jQuery out of the box solution for this or do I need to write my own function?

```
<div id="RSS">
    <div class="col-md-3 item">
        <div class="itemTitle"></div>
        <div class="itemDate"></div>
        <div class="itemContent"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 item">
        <div class="itemTitle"></div>
        <div class="itemDate"></div>
        <div class="itemContent"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 item">
        <div class="itemTitle"></div>
        <div class="itemDate"></div>
        <div class="itemContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function in jQuery called prependTo, which moves a element to the beginning of a given target. Check it out the example below.

```
$('.itemDate').each(function(){
    $(this).prependTo($(this).parent());
});
```

This code just move every itemDate into the beginning of every respective parent.